# Can't send mms with Hangouts

Tags: google-hangouts, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a Galaxy Note 4, running Android 6.0.1 and I can't send MMS with [Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk&hl=fr). I can receive and send MMS with the stock SMS app, but only receive MMS with Hangouts and I can't find whats is going wrong because it worked perfeclty fine before.

Hangouts is my default SMS app.

I deinstalled/reinstalled Hangouts, no changes.

I can sens MMS with other apps, I tried [Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra&hl=fr), but now my battery drains really fast.

Comment: Do you mean send and receive mms with your GV number, or your cellular number, and if the later, what carrier?

Comment: I am using my cellular number, and the phone carrier is SFR.

Comment: Check your APN settings as described here by your carrier: http://assistance.sfr.fr/runtime/mobile-et-tablette/offres-mobile/parametrer-apn-sfr.html

Comment: I have just checked and I have the same settings. The thing is that I never modified anything and it worked fine several weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

On many devices, messaging apps (even those with full access to SMS) are unable to send MMS messages unless they are set as the default SMS app.

This same issue affects to me on my Nexus 6P: my default SMS app is the Messenger app, and even though other messaging apps on my phone (Textra and Pulse) have access to SMS & MMS, neither can send MMS without being set as the default SMS app in Settings. Both of those apps prompt me to set them as the default SMS app when attempting to send MMS, I'm surprised that Hangouts does not.

So, to fix the issue: go to `Settings` -> `Apps` -> `gear icon in the top-left` -> `SMS app` -> `Hangouts`. Or, alternatively, search through Settings for "Default apps" or "SMS app".

**tl;dr:** Setting Hangouts as your default SMS app will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I misspoke, Hangouts IS my default SMS app. I was trying to say that I could send MMS with the "Stock" app, but not with Hangouts.

Comment: @Maxime So did the issue get resolved, or is this still happening? If it's still happening, mind trying to download an MMS app like Textra or Pulse and seeing if you can send MMS from those?

Comment: It seems to be working with Textra, it means my problem comes only from Hangouts. It bothers me alot because I'd like to find a solution without installing another app.

Comment: My battery drains REALLY fast since I installed Textra, have you heard similar cases with this app ?

Comment: @Maxime Eek sorry!! Either try deleting it or go into Settings -> Battery to see what's eating up juice.

Comment: I deleted the app it is much better now, but my problem with Hangouts is still here. Guess  I'll have to send my MMS with the stock app now.